# Swift for OsX WebFrameLoadDelegate doesn't works

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, swift, appdelegate

I am new in OSX developing and i am new in Swift. I want to write simple app with WebView.
I can load url, but I need to catch event when, WebView end loading content.

it's my app delegate.swift file:

```
import WebKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet var webview: WebView!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "google.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
        webview.mainFrame.loadRequest(request);
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    }
}
```

and i try to make WebFrameLoad delegate class:

```
import WebKit

class WebViewControllerDelegate: WebFrameLoadDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var webview: WebView!    
    override func didFinishLoadForFrame()
    {
        println("ok:");
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. And also i don't know how to set this Delegate to my WebView.
TY for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the `WebViewControllerDelegate` would be the class to have the webView as a property.

Move this code:

```
@IBOutlet var webview: WebView!

let url = NSURL(string: "google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
self.webview.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
```

to your `WebViewControllerDelegate`

You then also need to set the delegate for the WebView in your `WebViewControllerDelegate`

```
self.webView.delegate = self
```

If you don't set this, then the system will not call the delegate methods for you.

Finally you need to ensure that your class conforms to the WebFrameLoadDelegate protocol (which you have already done).

```
class WebViewControllerDelegate: WebFrameLoadDelegate{
```

The above means that you have a viewController which has a webView property, is conforming to the correct delegate protocol, **and is itself** the delegate for the webView.

Delegate methods defined inside the `WebViewControllerDelegate`  will then be called for you.

Comment: Xcode 6 Beta 6 states for me "Use of undeclared type 'WebFrameLoadDelegate'" when implementing it in a fresh project only for testing this. WebKit framework is referenced and imported. Do you have an idea about what I missed?

Comment: I set up [a public repository for reference code](https://bitbucket.org/Alomvar/testwebview).

Comment: Further addition: I posted [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547659/why-is-webframeloaddelegate-considered-as-undeclared) for this case now.