# Why is WebFrameLoadDelegate considered as undeclared?

Tags: xcode, macos, webview, swift, webkit

I have a basic Cocoa application having only a `WebView` in its window. The `WebKit.framework` reference is added to the Xcode **6 beta 6** project on OS X **10.9** (Mavericks). I would like to know when the `WebView` finished loading a page. So I created a `WebViewControllerDelegate` class inheriting `WebFrameLoadDelegate`. That already is the place where the problems start: Xcode tells me about `Use of undeclared type 'WebFrameLoadDelegate'`. Relating to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199641/swift-for-osx-webframeloaddelegate-doesnt-works?rq=1), it should not. Like already mentioned, the `WebKit.framework` is referenced by the project and the `WebKit` module imported in the Swift class file. I also see the `WebFrameLoadDelegate.h` in the "Headers" folder in the left side bar of Xcode, underneath the `WebKit.framework`.

The root of all evil is line `11` in file `TestWebView/WebViewControllerDelegate.swift` (I forgot to  remove the comments which I omitted here), the class declaration and protocol reference.

```
import WebKit

class WebViewControllerDelegate: WebFrameLoadDelegate {
    func didFinishLoadForFrame() {
        NSLog("didFinishLoadForFrame()")
    }
}
```

The `AppDelegate`, which sets everything up:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewControllerDelegate: WebViewControllerDelegate!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        self.webView.frameLoadDelegate = self.webViewControllerDelegate
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")))
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {}
}
```

For further information, please take a look at the code in my [my public repository](https://bitbucket.org/Alomvar/testwebview) which I created for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebFrameLoadDelegate` is an informal protocol, so you can't declare conformance to it. Just inherit from `NSObject` and implement the desired methods.

Also, note that the Swift method name is `webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!)`, not just `didFinishLoadForFrame()`.

```
class WebViewControllerDelegate: NSObject { // WebFrameLoadDelegate
      override func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
      NSLog("didFinishLoadForFrame()")
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code in my repository accordingly for others with same or similar problem to see a working example.